# Dotted Line in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using the chart from [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org) to create my charts, and what I want to do is have 2 horizontal lines on the same chart, but one of them should be dotted. 
I have tried to find solution on Google without success.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please provide some of your code to make your question more answerable. Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the `border-dash` property for particular dataset. You can specify [border length & spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setLineDash). E.g  `borderDash: [10,5]`

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'legend1',
            data: [12, 19, 3],
            borderDash: [10,5]
        },{
            label: 'legend2',
            data: [22, 9, 13],
          
        }]
      
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js" ></script>

<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv" style="height:500px">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```